# Internet speed in Linux via command

Tags: linux, performance, internet, wget

I am running several sites and I was trying `wget` and I noticed slow speed. So I suspect that my sites are taking considerable amount of traffic.

Question is, how I can really detect the total consumption of traffic in and out to know the real speed of my server?

This is to know if I am really using a dedicated server or a shared internet line.

Answer (score 3):

Try [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/).  You'll need to install it, since it's not a built-in in any distros I know of, but it's a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

`netstat -i` will show in and out packets for each logical interface

and `netstat -i 1` for example will give you a very crude measurement of speed.

Comment: what does this mean: `eth0       1500   0 13413936      0      0      0 16313092      0      0      0 BMRU`

Comment: do yourself a favor and read the man page for netstat.  Basically that means you have 13413936 packets coming in on interface eth0 and 13413936 going out.  But note if this is the first time you've executed netstat this figure will be meaningless since it represents the total number odf packets since the last time the box booted up

Comment: @TDSii: `MTU` == Max Transmission Unit, the largest packet that can be sent without fragmentation; `Met` is the Metric for that interface, the relative cost of sending packets on that interface rather than other interfaces; `RX-OK` is the number of packets received without errors, `RX-ERR` is the number of packets that failed checksums or lengths, `RX-DRP` is number of packets dropped, `RX-OVR` is probably receive buffer overruns (too many packets too quickly); `TX-` metrics mirror the `RX-` metrics, and the `Flg` column shows the flags found via `ifconfig`

Answer (score 1):

`iptraf` is another good tool.

Comment: I do second that!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor bandwidth usage in realtime (with nice ASCII graphics :D ) you can try [nload](http://www.roland-riegel.de/nload/), too.